# Windows 8.1 MongoDB 27017 errno: 10061 "Connection couldnt be made Target machine actively refuses it"

Tags: windows, mongodb

Full list of error:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: test
2015-10-25T11:26:55.350+0200 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2015-10-25T11:26:55.353+0200 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

Service is running fine:

```
C:\Program Files\mongodb\Server\3.0\bin\mongod.exe --service --config D:\Documents\Work\mongodb\mongod.cfg
```

I saw already solutions here but nothing helped

`netstat.exe -0` and `netstat.exe -any` dosen't show 27017 port as used by some App or process.

I have this mongod.cfg file

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: D:\Documents\Work\mongodb\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: D:\Documents\Work\mongodb\db
net:
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1
    port: 28018
```

But MongoDB still connects to same 27017 port
What i have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client does not know that you want to connect to a server on a non-default port.

Connect using the `--port` parameter:

```
mongo.exe --port 28018
```

Or just let the server listen on the default port.

Comment: Thanks it helped: But why are `net:` section ignored in a `.cfg` file?

Comment: It is not ignored; your server runs on port 28018 doesn't it? It's just that the Mongo client simply does not read your server config (as you can use it to connect to any server, not just the ones running on your machine).

Answer (score -1):

Execute the following steps:

1. Go to control panel
2. Click program and features
3. Select `mongodb`
4. Right click
5. Repair it
6. Open your shell(cmd)
7. Type _  "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe"
8. Enter

Done